# Keypress don't work on some Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, dom-events, jquery-terminal

I have [issue with Android](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/issues/39) in jQuery Terminal, I've almost fix it, it work on devices I've tested. [Demo](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/android.php). But it seems that keypress event don't fire at all (It should echo keypress) on some devices.

On mobile I have code that keep focus on textarea (I resued clipboard) so virtual keyboard is open.

I have this code in keydown:

```
function keydown_event(e) {
     ...
     if (enabled) {
        ... 
            } else {
                // this get fired while typing
                $.terminal.active().echo('keydown else');
                prevent_keypress = false;
                return;
            }
            // this will prevent for instance backspace to go back one page
            prevent_keypress = true;
            $.terminal.active().echo('keydown return false');
            return false;
        }
     ...
     }
}
```

and in keypress:

```
    var doc = $(document.documentElement || window);
    doc.bind('keypress.cmd', function(e) {
        var result;
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.which === 99) { // CTRL+C
            return;
        }
        // this line never get fired while typing
        $.terminal.active().echo('keypress');
        if (prevent_keypress) {
            $.terminal.active().echo('prevent');
            return;
        }
        if (!reverse_search && $.isFunction(options.keypress)) {
            result = options.keypress(e);
        }
        if (result === undefined || result) {
            ...
            self.insert(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
            ...
        } else {
            return result;
        }
    }).bind('keydown.cmd', keydown_event);
```

Anybody had same issue and know how to fix it, it's hard for me because it work on my devices.

**UPDATE** I've create [simple test to isolate the problem](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/test.php) and it seems that keypress is not fired at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to fix (almost) the issue by detecting if keypress was not fired and get value from clipboard (for mobile the content it's always the same as terminal input)

```
var no_keypress;
doc.bind('keydown.cmd', function(e) {
    no_keypress = true;
    ...
}).bind('keypress.cmd', function(e) {
    no_keypress = false;
    ...
}).bind('keyup.cmd', function() {
    if (no_keypress) {
        // Some Androids don't fire keypress - #39
        self.set(clip.val());
    }
});
```